# ListBox Value containing links

Tags: html, seo, listbox, google-crawlers

hi I am currently working on improving the SEO on a website containing dropdown list menu. currently when you select options and then submit a javascript is redirecting you to the next page

I heard from some people that i could put the link i want indexed in the value of the dropdown list and that google crawler would trap it as a link and index it.

I personaly do think its not gonna work considering that a Value proprety is not a link href and i dont think google crawler would be parsing every option value and try to see if its a valid link

so the question is ... what do u guys think about that ... is it possible to simply put my links in the value field or should i build a hidden menu in plain html ( li // ul with  tags containing the links) somewhere in my page

if ever crawlers can trap links in the value of an option .. do i need to put the whole link http://.../page/page.html or can i simply put /page/page.html

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items in the select element are important and should be followed by google, you should probably work out a different way to display them.

Maybe a rollover menu?

Comment: yep im just trying to get the fastest method to save on the client budget ;) ty tho

Comment: Another option is to keep it the way you have it but add a sitemap.